# How can I ask for the type class of a variable?

Tags: ocaml, reason, bucklescript

I'm trying to learn ReasonML, and I'm doing some koans to help me with that task. One of the koans I'm trying to code is about asking for the type of a list after converting it to an array. I know that there are operators in some languages like Haskell (`:t`) where we can ask for the type of a variable. Is there any equivalent to `:t` for ReasonML? Or it shouldn't make sense to check if `Array.of_list` returns an array because the compiler ensures that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler will ensure that it is an array (unless the type system has been circumvented, of course), so I'm not sure I see the point of the exercise. Also, I believe `:t` is a `ghci` command, not a Haskell operator. `rtop`, the Reason REPL, will print the type of each evaluated expression without needing to ask, so there's no need for a `:t` command either as far as I know.

Reason/OCaml also does not carry around runtime type information. However, if you compile to JavaScript you can use the [`Js.Types` module](https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/api/Js.Types.html) to access JavaScript runtime type information. Specifically, `Js.Types.classify` will return the JS type of any value, but of course will not be able to distinguish a Reason/OCaml list from an array because it knows only JavaScript. `Js.typeof` is another, more lightweight alternative that will return a string instead of a variant.

Comment: Yeah, I ended thinking the same. So I'm just checking that `Array.of_list([1, 2, 3])` is equal to `[|1, 2, 3|]`.

Comment: @gabrielperales a unit test like `assert(Array.of_list([1, 2, 3]) == [|1, 2, 3|])` is I think not necessary because it's checking the library function is implemented correctly. Usually you would take that as a given :-)

Comment: @Yawar, I know, but it is for a koan. The solution won't be given, just the test to check that the solution is ok.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know much about Reason, but `utop` (an improved OCaml REPL) provides the `#typeof` directive to inspect the type of an expression:

```
let a = 42;;
val a : int = 42

#typeof "a";;
val a : int
```

Note that this is only a REPL tool. In OCaml, types are not available on runtime: they are stripped during compilation. You can learn more about the OCaml compilation process [here](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/the-compiler-frontend-parsing-and-type-checking.html).

---

As pointed out by [@Rizo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279580/rizo) in the comments, there also is the `#show` directive, which is even available in the standard OCaml REPL:

```
let a = 43;;
val a : int = 43

#show a;;
val a : int
```

Comment: Another option is to use `#show <identifier>`. This will show the type of a value, type definition and even module or interface signature.